# Sonarqube : Boolean literals should not be redundant

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have the following nice one liner :

```
boolean outcome = count > 0 ? false : true;
```

But from sonaqube I get 'Remove the literal "false" boolean value'

The [solution](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/clumsy/RSPEC-1125) seems to assume you can re-write as a function

But even that function will have that simple one liner and put me in the same position, I don't quite understand how to fix ? Ideas ?

Comment: try `boolean outcome = !(count > 0)`

Comment: The issue is that you are doing extra gymnastics on an operation that already produces a boolean.

Comment: Thank you ! Not sure why could not think of that

Comment: The shorthand `if` sentence is still a complete if in the eye of the compiler, and that is what sonarqube is complaining about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you are doing *extra gymnastics* on an operation that already produces a `boolean`.

If I write out what you have coded in full syntax:

```
boolean outcome;

if(count > 0){
  outcome = false;
} else {
 outcome = true;
}
```

essentially, you are reversing the `count > 0`

So try

```java
boolean outcome = !(count > 0)
```

or even better

```java
boolean outcome = count <= 0
```

Comment: just loved that `The issue is that you are doing extra gymnastics ` comment, made my day!! :p

Answer (score 0):

For reference to others I was being dumb and SonarQube correct in reporting the above as it's doing more than needed. Correct code is:

```
boolean outcome = count > 0;
```

you do not need the ternary statement the result of count > 0 is a true/false value...

So as stated above to reverse that outcome is simple

```
 boolean outcome = !(count > 0);
```

Comment: Except that https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1940 says that comparisons should not be reversed.  `count <= 0` would be better.